# Dismissing alerts in bootstrap 5.1 and Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, alert, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5.1 [alerts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/alerts/) to show specific messages upon an Ajax call.
Also, I would like to dismiss the alert if needed. For that, bootstrap allows to have a dismiss button.

Here is my php :

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert" style="display:none;" id="message-response-given">
<button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```

And the relevant js for the Ajax call :

```
document.getElementById("message-response-given").innerHTML = res.message;
$('#message-response-given').fadeIn();
```

This shows the message BUT not the button after the Ajax call.

I have read the following (bootstrap alerts, same link as above) :

> When an alert is dismissed, the element is completely removed from the page structure. If a keyboard user dismisses the alert using the close button, their focus will suddenly be lost and, depending on the browser, reset to the start of the page/document. For this reason, we recommend including additional JavaScript that listens for the closed.bs.alert event and programmatically sets focus() to the most appropriate location in the page. If you’re planning to move focus to a non-interactive element that normally does not receive focus, make sure to add tabindex="-1" to the element.

But I have no clue how to do it.....

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the button html when you set:

```
document.getElementById("message-response-given").innerHTML = res.message;
```

You need to call `append` and pass the message as a parameter instead. Since you are using jQuery you can simplify your script to a chained one-liner:

```
$('#message-response-given').append(res.message).fadeIn();
```

For example:

```js
$('#message-response-given').append("message").fadeIn();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert" style="display:none;" id="message-response-given">
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Many thanks for this answer ! This indeed allows to have the dismiss button (albeit appending the message multiple time if one does not refresh the page and submit a form multiple times. No big deal). But if I dismiss the alert, stay one the same page and re-submit the form, the alert does not show up. Is there a way to show the alert again without refreshing ?